# How to prevent crashes when parameter is null

Tags: asp.net, sql, syntax, parameters, null

i am inserting the value of dynamic controls into the db like so;

```
Dim ae1 As DropDownList = FindControl("AreasExpertise1")
        If (ae1 IsNot Nothing) Then
            x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areasexpertise1", ae1.SelectedValue)
        End If
```

then in my query i have parameters like so;

```
INSERT INTO [foo] ([etc], [etc], [etc], [areasexpertise1], [areasexpertise2])
VALUES (@etc, @etc, @etc, @areasexpertise1, @areasexpertise2)
```

When the user fills out the form, they see only areasexpertise1 and have to press a button to dynamically insert another area of expertise...

If they only have 1 area of expertise, the query crashes and says 'must declare variable @areasexpertise2.

Please can you tell me a way to either insert nulls when the parameters are empty, or to ignore them?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in DBNull.Value, like this:

```
If (ae1 IsNot Nothing) Then
    x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areasexpertise1", ae1.SelectedValue)
Else
   x.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areasexpertise1", DBNull.Value)
End If
```